# PDFBOX unable to find number of pixels which contain a particular character

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using `PDFBOX` for pdf creation. In pdfbox is there any function which will give the font size in pixels? For example letters `A` and `a`, will take different spaces for printing.  Where obviosely `A` will take more pixels than `a`. How can I get find number of pixels supposed to take a character or a word?

Comment: Have you tried PDFont.getStringWidth() ? It returns the width of the string in 1/1000 units of text space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the concept of pixels is a bit vague.
Generally a document is of a certain size, e.g. inches/cm etc.

The javadocs for PDFBox shows that PDFont has a few methods to determine the width of a string or character.
Take a look at for example these pages:

[getStringWidth(String text)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html#getStringWidth(java.lang.String))

[getWidth(int code)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html#getWidth(int))

[getWidthFromFont(int code)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html#getWidthFromFont(int))

These units are in 1/1000 of an [Em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)). Also see this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)).

For a full example:

```
float fontSize = 12;
String text = "a";

PDRectangle pageSize = PDRectangle.A4;
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;


PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(pageSize);
doc.addPage(page);

PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page);
stream.setFont( font, fontSize );

// charWidth is in points multiplied by 1000.
double charWidth = font.getStringWidth(text);
charWidth *= fontSize; // adjust for font-size.

stream.beginText();
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0,10);

float widthLeft = pageSize.getWidth();
widthLeft *= 1000.0; //due to charWidth being x1000.

while(widthLeft > charWidth){
    stream.showText(text);
    widthLeft -= charWidth;
}

stream.close();
// Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
doc.save( "example.pdf");
doc.close();
```

Comment: can say in which unit like cm or inch or mm does `getStringWidth(String text)` returns?

Comment: @@Tilman Hausher is pdfbox follows all in units.Like page width and all returns in units?

Comment: Various methods return various types of units. E.g. getStringWidth is 1/1000 of the width, while the page is 1x. The best approach is to carefully read the javadocs.